# CSV Lookup and save to a new File

Tags: csv, lookup

I do have two `.csv` The first one looks like this:

```
train,
car,
horse,
```

the second `.csv` contains

```
bike, 2,
car, 3,
ship, 0,
horse, 1,
Jet, 2,
train, 1,
```

Now I need a new `.csv` when the first matches with the second. the output should be like this:

```
train, 1,
car, 3,
horse, 1,
```

I've tried some batch scripts, but it doesn't what I need. It should run automaticly once a day, on a Windows Server. Im looking for a script (bat).

Can someone help?

Comment: What exactly have you tried already? What programming language do you want to use? Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question.

Comment: It is not a csv problem, but only how to select lines from a file according to a list from another file. `grep` is your friend here: `grep -f first.csv second.csv` is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a csv problem, but only how to select lines from a file according to a list from another file.

In the Unix world, `grep` would be your friend here: `grep -f first.csv second.csv`.

The Windows equivalent of `grep` is `findstr`, even with a different syntax. But you can simply use:

```
findstr /g:first.csv second.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below one

```
> cat a.csv
train,
car,
horse,


> cat b.csv
bike, 2,
car, 3,
ship, 0,
horse, 1,
Jet, 2,
train, 1,

>for i in $(cat a.csv)
> do
> grep -i $i b >> c.sv
> done

cat c.csv
train, 1,
car, 3,
horse, 1,
```

Comment: Sorry I thought you are trying it in bash unix script